# Rspec failing on API create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

Rspec keeps failing on this create action, i.e. the event is a Nil object when the test runs. The other tests passes on all of my user and user token authentication secttions fine. It's loading the FFaker/Factory-Girl data properly. Can't seem to find an answer anywhere.

**events_controller_rspec.rb**

```
describe "POST #create" do
context "when is successfully created" do
  before(:each) do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    @event_attributes = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:event)
    api_authorization_header user.auth_token
    post :create, { user_id: user.id, event: @event_attributes }, format: :json
  end

  it "renders the JSON representation for the event record just created" do
    event_response = json_response[:event]
    expect(event_response[:name]).to eql @event_attributes[:name]
  end

  it { should respond_with 201 }
end
```

**events_controller.rb**

```
def create
 event = current_user.events.build(event_params)

 if event.save
  render json: event, status: 201, location: [:api, event]
 else
  render json: { errors: event.errors }, status: 422
 end
end

private

def event_params
  params.require(:event).permit(:name, :user_id)
end

end
```

app/concerns/authenticatable.rb

```
module Authenticable
 # Devise methods overwrites

 def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find_by(auth_token: request.headers['Authorization'])
 end
end
```

**Rspec Results**

```
Failures:

1) Api::V1::EventsController POST #create when is successfully created renders the JSON representation for the event record just created
 Failure/Error: expect(event_response[:name]).to eql @event_attributes[:name]

 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
 # ./spec/controllers/api/v1/events_controller_spec.rb:75:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) Api::V1::EventsController POST #create when is successfully created should respond with 201
 Failure/Error: it { should respond_with 201 }
   Expected response to be a 201, but was 422
 # ./spec/controllers/api/v1/events_controller_spec.rb:78:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: It's difficult to debug and reproduce your problem. 
The response has 422 as status code, so maybe the problem is with validations (?) of the object event. You could try to save with exclamation mark (`event.save!`) to raise an exception if validations not pass.
Next you could try to debug (with byebug or some puts) your spec, example: puts to stdout the response that you receive, so in your spec add `puts json_response`.

Comment: This was a good start and helped me understand some of the issues saving into the database. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `event_params` method tells in `params.require(:event).permit(:name, :user_id)` that the `user_id` needs to be part of the `event` attributes.

Change:

```
post :create, { user_id: user.id, event: @event_attributes }, format: :json
```

to

```
post :create, { event: @event_attributes.merge(user_id: user.id) }, format: :json
```

Comment: This indeed solved the problem partially, thank you! The other issue is a validation. I'll mark this one correct, but any follow-up would be helpful.

I had to add your code and delete this code to make it work:

**Event.rb**

`validates :name, presence: true`

Otherwise, it wouldn't save the post into the database.

Comment: Seems like `FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:event)` does not return a hash with a valid name. How did you define an event in FactoryGirl?

Comment: `FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :event do
    name { FFaker::Product.product_name }`

Comment: Looks good to me. No idea what is going wrong. Perhaps ask a new question with this specific problem?